# Weird bug returning a CGSize in UICollectionView sizeForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have variable widths in my UICollectionView and in my `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` function, I ultimately return a `CGSize`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var width: CGFloat = indexPath.row == 0 ? 37 : 20 // default paddings based on spacing in cell
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        width += listingsFilter.stringValue.width(withConstrainedHeight: 28, font: font)
    } else {
        let string = viewModel.valueRangeForButton[indexPath.row - 1]
        width += string.width(withConstrainedHeight: 28, font: font)
    }

    print(width) // some decimal e.g. 138.1239581
    let w: CGFloat = width.rounded() // rounded e.g. 13

    return CGSize(width: w, height: 28)
}
```

If I stub the return value with a number for the width, say 128, rather than have a variable, the collection view respects `UIEdgeInsets`. If I return the `CGSize` with a variable for the width, `UIEdgeInsets` gets ignored for every element but the first and the last.

I feel like I found some deep `CoreGraphics` bug.

For the last two lines, if I change them to

```
let x: CGFloat = 128 // or 128.0, doesn't matter
return CGSize(width: x, height: 28)
```

It still doesn't work. I've tried returning a `CGSize` with the `Int` initializer. I've tried casting to Ints and back to `CGFloat`s. Nothing seems to work.

I've narrowed down the problem to this point. It doesn't have anything to do with the `width` code above it (which is a string extension) or anything else.

Super weird. Anyone have experience with this?

**Edit:** Some images

Top one is with `CGSize(width: w, height: 28)` where `w` is a `CGFloat` that could equal 128 or whatever other value. Bottom one is `CGSize(width: 128, height: 28)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: In comment do you mean `e.g. 138`?

Comment: Urgh! I know that problem but I can't remember the solution ... I'll come back to you when I do! But there *is* a solution :)

Comment: @alistra Any number, whether an int or a cgfloat

Comment: @HAS that's re-assuring! Looking forward to hearing back

Comment: @ZackShapiro what do you mean by `UIEdgeInsets`? you mean `37 : 0` margin or any kind of `contentInsets` within your custom cell?

Comment: @MertBuran ```func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 15, right: 10)
    }```

Comment: but `insetForSectionAt` isn't related to `minimumInteritemSpacing`. in your screenshots, `sectionInsets` seems to stay the same while `interitemSpacing` is changing. for more info on `sectionInsets`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionviewflowlayout/1402862-sectioninset

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just tried `flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 15, right: 10)` and `flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10` while commenting out `insetForSection`. The same issue is still happening: when returning a `CGSize` where `width` is a variable instead of a hard-coded value, the `UIEdgeInsets` just get thrown out

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? do you want spaces between respective widths? as per screenshots shown, the first need minimumintrimspacing adjustments and second has a width + 20 accroding to your code, so are you sure that you want to add 20 width to width of label ?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve widths respective to the text and potential image in each collection view cell with 15pt insets top & bottom and 10pt insets between collection view cells

Comment: I'd suggest you place a breakpoint on the `return` line in the function and examine what `w` actually is. The assumptions you have may be wrong

Comment: I did that before posting this but I will again. I can create a `CGFloat` right above that return and put it in the `CGSize` initializer and this will happen. It's not going on in the `width` function

Comment: Why don't you use auto layout? That way the cells will auto size themselves and you won't have to deal with all of this...

Comment: Because this project was already architected this way :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue few months ago. As far as I remember it was really annoying trying to fix this (as in your case) but ridiculously simple.
You need to make sure that your class inherits from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. It inherits from `UICollectionViewDelegate`. That should make the trick. 
 Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It already inherits from it. The code in my original post is from a delegate function in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand from op's question

to move content within cell you need

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:
    UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 0, bottom: 15, right: 0)
}
```

to move spaces between respective cells you need

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 15
}
```

be sure that you confront the delegate UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't it. The question states that returning a `CGSize` with a number for the `width` computed and stored in a variable and passed into the `CGSize` init causes different behavior than a hard-coded `CGFloat` passed into the `CGSize` init.

Comment: isnt this what you commented---> "I'm trying to achieve widths respective to the text and potential image in each collection view cell with 15pt insets top & bottom and 10pt insets between collection view cells – Zack Shapiro yesterday"

Comment: Yes, but I still need to get different widths for each cell which requires hitting the `sizeForItem` function returns this bug

Answer (score 0):

Having never even tried to return a hardcoded value instead of a variable from `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()`, I've always assumed that `UIEdgeInsets` weren't even supposed to affect the spacing between the cells of a `UICollectionView`, but only the spaces surrounding an entire section of cells.  Looks like `UIEdgeInsets` is not intended to affect the spacing between the cells, in which case Apple's bug is the reverse of what it seems to be --  that `UIEdgeInsets` is oddly affecting the spacing between cells in one outlier case, when in fact it was never intended to do so in any scenario.  This red herring had you reasonably assume that there must be a reliable and programmatic way to get `UIEdgeInsets` to set the spacing between `UICollectionView` cells.  I have yet to find a programmatic way to do so.  When I found the following storyboard solution I stopped looking for one.

After having spent a great deal of time tweaking `UICollectionViews` to get them to look the way I want, I have found that the only reliable way to set the spacing between their cells is to use storyboard settings as follows:

In the storyboard, select your `UICollectionView`, go to the attributes inspector, find the "Min Spacing" section, and type in the "For Cells" box the value you'd like (in your case, 10).  The "For Cells" value is the horizontal spacing between cells.  Do the same for the "For Lines" value, which is the vertical spacing between cells.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below,

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    collectionView?.delegate = self
    collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let x: CGFloat = 50 + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(50)) // or 128.0, doesn't matter
    return CGSize(width: x, height: 28)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 0, bottom: 15, right: 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 15
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "aaa", for: indexPath)
}


override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

}

Result is [image]

Answer (score -1):

It's not related to `UIEdgeInsets`, it relates to `width` that you're calculating in code. When you set `width: 128`, the width provided for your cells are bigger than what they actually need (let's say 90), hence depending on your `UICollectionViewCell`'s design, it might **feel** there is an `UIEdgeInsets` for each cell.

## To solve your problem:

If you're using IB, you can set `cellSpacing` and `lineSpacing` from IB, other-wise you have to implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`